# How do I read config.i18n.default_locale from a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, scope

How do I read my Rails application's default_locale from inside a gem? I'm running Rails 3.2.6 on REE 1.8.7

This isn't working for me:

```
module MyModule
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    begin
      puts "test #{config.i18n.default_locale}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: @apneadiving That gave me "en" where I've set my application's default to "en-GB"

Comment: And `Rails.configuration.default_locale`? The potential issue here is the load order which could be configured thanks to methods presented here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#initialization-events

Comment: Maybe it's more `Rails.configuration.i18n.default_locale`, no computer to check.

Comment: @apneadiving Sorry, neither of those worked and I'm not sure what to try from that link. It's giving the error: undefined method `config' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it like this:

```
module MyModule
  class Railtie < Rails::Railtie
    config.to_prepare do
        Rails.configuration.i18n.default_locale
    end
  end
end
```